# An app for RFID card UID emulation?

Tags: android, rfid

Is there an simple app that would allow Android phone with NFC capability to emulate a ISO 14443 card's UID (10 digit identifier)? Ī'm working on a small project that uses simple authentication via RFID card (only uses UID, none of the advanced encryption stuff), and it's time consuming to use rewritable cards to replace the IDs over and over again for testing - I'd prefere to have an app that allows to quickly simulate any ID necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not - and using "just the UID" is anyway not good practice.
Just think for for your use case - your "authentication" is already be a joke if you can bypass it with rewritable UID cards, but would be completel useless if there would be such an app ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear enough - this is not used to "authenticate" users - it's a in-house project for simple identification of workers at the facility to log when they start/stop using workbenches, so as a result there is literally no need for any security - just a quicker alternative to the previous practice of manually entering 4 digit employee number by pinpad, which was uncomfortable with gloves/dirty hands. Just a matter of convenience, not security.